# optimistically save session in authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, authlogic-oauth

I am trying to create similar functionality as this gem authlogix-rpx, which optimistically saves the session/user object even if some of the validated fields are missing.

http://github.com/tardate/authlogic_rpx/tree/master/lib/authlogic_rpx (line 167)

With this gem it's possible to create the record that does not meet validation criteria and later on call the registration_complete? method which return false if all the validations do not pass.

I am not sure how this save is taking place, in my gem (which is an add on to authlogic using oauth2) I have tried doing save(false), save_with_vaidation_false but nothign really works, the validations fail and the record get saved.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand exactly what you're looking for. You want to save without validation and then check if the resource is valid after it's been saved?

Comment: Yes. If the user is authenticating with oauth, during the first time login I want to automatically create a user account (invalid because oauth does not provide any email/username type fields), and redirect to teh profile page, right after that asking teh user to complete the profile. My app needs the email/username etc, hence I need the validations, but I just want to skip it during the oauth login, just to let the user in first.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run `user.save(false)` to save the user and then use `user.errors.full_messages` to access the validation error messages.

Or you could provide the `:on` parameter to your validations to restrict them to `:create`, `:update` or both (`:save`)

```
validates_presence_of :email, :on=>:update
```